# how to cancel alarm in android

Tags: android, eclipse

i just edit my previous question(android pattern lock).
thanks for your help..
Now i want to know how to cancel alarm.

protected void setReminder(Date reminder_date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    String al_date = sdf.format(reminder_date);
    Log.d("alarm_date", al_date);
    int r_day, r_month, r_year;

    Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
    ca.setTime(reminder_date);

    r_day = ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    r_month = ca.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    r_year = ca.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    Log.d("new month", String.valueOf(r_month));
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(),
            Locale.getDefault());

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, r_month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, r_year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, r_day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10); // HOUR
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15); // MIN
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // SEC
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
            myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

int level=getAPILevel();
if(level == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
}
if(level < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
}
    Log.d("alarm","on");
}
```

this is how i set alarm. this works fine...but the problem is it send notification even the time expired.

this is my receiver class.
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

   Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
   context.startService(service1);

}
```

}

MyAlarmService.class

@SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "deprecation" })
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);

```
   mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),HomePage.class);

   Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Time for payment!", System.currentTimeMillis());
   intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

   PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "Finance Manager", "Time for payment!", pendingNotificationIntent);
   Log.d("Notification","send");
   mManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: Please refer this link, https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pattern+lock+android

Comment: Please refer this link https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/

Comment: man you should have googled it once `https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+create+pattern+lock+app+in+android`

Comment: thanks for your help...now please help me on this..i googled it and i find some solved answers about cancelling alarm but didn't understand that method...